# Landscape printing using an Android application on a 2inch Bluetooth dot-matrix printer

Tags: android, bluetooth, landscape

We have built an Android application to print bills in portrait mode to a 2" mobile Bluetooth dot-matrix printer. Our customer now has a (strange) requirement to print the same bills in landscape mode, but there seems to be some constraints in either the dot-matrix printer configuration itself or our code, and we are unable to do so.

Is it possible to change the orientation of the bills so that the bill information can be printed out in landscape format (for any 2" Bluetooth dot-matrix printer)?

Comment: Any application can be build on both mode , portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Yes, this application also prints in landscape on a mobile thermal bluetooth printer, but somehow, is unable to on the mobile dotmatrix bluetooth printer.

Answer (score -1):

Print by creating a landscape layout on a potrait using rotation functions on views.